# Load form responses with script in sheet - Create initial forms with nothing but an ID number

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a simple form with just a few fields.  I need to load data from a spreadsheet and create the form responses.  I need 10,000 responses with for example serial number 1-10,000 as the only entry.  The remaining fields will be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myFormID = 'Put_Form_ID_Here';
var howManyToSubmit = 10;//How many form submissions

function makeResponses(id,howMany) {
  var allQuestionItems,firstQuestion,frm,i,newAnswer,newRezpnz;

  id = id?id:myFormID;//If an id was passed to the function - use it
  if (!id) {return;};//If there is no id to get the Form - quit
  frm = FormApp.openById(id);//Get a reference to the Form
  
  allQuestionItems = frm.getItems();//Get all questions in the Form

  firstQuestion = allQuestionItems[0];
  
  for (i=1;i<howManyToSubmit;i+=1) {
    newRezpnz = frm.createResponse();
    //Logger.log('thisAnswer: ' + thisAnswer)

    newAnswer = firstQuestion.asTextItem().createResponse(i.toString());
    
    newRezpnz.withItemResponse( newAnswer );
    newRezpnz.submit();//submit a new response
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you Sandy.  This script is doing what I needed.  Only problem is when it runs I receive an error after a dozen or more loops.  The error is "Sorry, the form response could not be submitted."  I tried putting in a utilities.sleep(200) in the loop to slow things down.  I added a line to see how many responses there were and adjusted the for loop to pick up from where it ended.  However this will take ma quite awhile to enter 10,000 responses.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry,  figured it out.  I had another script running at the same time also accessing the form.  Turned the script off and good to go.  Thanks!